# Check all CheckBoxes in Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

I copied the code from the below link
[Check all CheckBoxes in Telerik nested Grid in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685944/check-all-checkboxes-in-telerik-nested-grid-in-c-sharp/13883592#13883592)

How ever when I run the code I get this error:

`0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method`

and the `'checkAll(this, gridToCheckAll);'` is highlighted in the dynamic run code with the error.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
var gridToCheckAll = '<%= rgFiles.ClientID %>';

    function checkAll(sender, containerID) {
        var checked = sender.checked;
        var container = document.getElementById(containerID);
        var checkboxes = container.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = 0, l = checkboxes.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i] != sender && !checkboxes[i].disabled)
                checkboxes[i].checked = checked;
        }
    }
</script>

<telerik:RadGrid id="rgFiles" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="NotSet" BackColor="darkgray"
    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="50" AllowSorting="True"
    EnableEmbeddedScripts="true" 
    OnNeedDataSource="rgFiles_NeedDataSource"  
    OnItemCommand="rgFiles_ItemCommand" 
    OnItemDataBound="rgFiles_ItemDataBound" 
    OnItemEvent="rgFiles_ItemEvent"
    AllowMultiRowSelection="true" Skin="" 
    AllowFilteringByColumn="true" EnableLinqExpressions="false" >
    <MasterTableView  HorizontalAlign="NotSet" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="True"
        Font-Size="7pt" AllowCustomSorting="true" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="1" BorderWidth="0px"
        TableLayout="Fixed" AlternatingItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" 
        CommandItemStyle-Wrap="false" >
        <FooterStyle CssClass="datagrid-footerstyle" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <ItemStyle CssClass="datagrid-itemstyle" Wrap="false" Font-Size="XX-Small" Height="15px"/>
        <EditItemStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#E0E0E0" ForeColor="DimGray" HorizontalAlign="Left" Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric"
            NextPageText="next" PrevPageText="prev" AlwaysVisible="True" />
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="datagrid-headerstyle" ForeColor="White" />
        <FilterItemStyle BackColor="#a9a9a9" />
        <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="datagrid-alternatingitemstyle" />
        <ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="False">
            <HeaderStyle Width="19px" />
        </ExpandCollapseColumn>
        <RowIndicatorColumn Visible="False">
            <HeaderStyle Width="20px" />
        </RowIndicatorColumn>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn SortExpression="Reviewed"  DataField="Reviewed" HeaderText="<input type='checkbox' id='checkAll' onclick='checkAll(this, gridToCheckAll);'>" 
                UniqueName="Reviewed" AllowFiltering="false" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbReviewed" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cbReviewed_CheckedChanged" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top"></ItemStyle>
                <HeaderStyle Width="50px"></HeaderStyle>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 4):

maybe you should use a Telerik:GridClientSelectColumn in place of your templateColumn, Telerik has the built in functionality that you're looking for.

API: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-column-types.html

```
<radgrid...>
<masterTableView ... >
   <columns>
      <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="ClientSelectColumn">
           <HeaderStyle Width="35px" />
       </telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>
    </columns>
</MasterTableView>
 <ClientSettings>
       <ClientEvents OnRowSelected="RowSelected" OnRowDeselected="RowDeselected"/>
 </ClientSettings>
</radgrid>


       function RowDeselected(sender, eventArgs){
            //your code
        }

        function RowSelected(sender,eventArgs)
        {
            var MasterTable = sender.get_masterTableView();
            var selectedRows = MasterTable.get_selectedItems();
            var selectedRowsCount = selectedRows.length;
            //etc
        }
```

Comment: I have tried that. The issue is I have to tell when a user selects the checkbox and update the record at that time with the appropriate boolean value from that box, because the user can choose to mark it as reviewed or change it to unreviewed,  I also use the selected rows to zip the files together and stream at one time if the user chooses.  So the box is being used for multiple different functionalities. the GridClientSelectColumn doesn't allow for the detection of when the client changed the checkbox that I have found anywhere.

Comment: I believe with what you've described this will still work.  You can attach the clientEvents  OnRowSelected, OnRowDeselected to detect when a user has clicked or unclicked that row.

Comment: That almost works except I need it to be able to call the server side code that does some handling prior to the update.  things like is the person authorized to make the update, or can they only download the files. stuff like that

Answer (score 0):

I know I am too late to answer the original question. But still wanted to provide my feedback for other developers.

Change your java script method name from checkAll() to anything else at both places and you will not see this nasty JS error :)